# Can I control the apps in the share menu?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-share

I'm using the `open` method of `react-native-share` to share an html file on an android device.

When I share the file I thought there would be an option to share to the browser. There is no such option.

The [documentation](https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-open#supported-options) suggests that I might be able to limit the apps in the share menu.  I don't see anything that suggests that I can add apps to the share menu.

Is it possible to control the apps that appear in the share menu?